# swift: completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData) not work

Tags: swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, swift4

I get push notification, but not display notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Message ID2: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

print Message ID2 it's OK :

> Message ID2: [AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("TEXT"):
>   NEXT, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.POSITION"): ticket,
>   AnyHashable("POSITION"): ticket, AnyHashable("TITLE"): TEST,
>   AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1534328572978948%f6f48aeff6f48aef,
>   AnyHashable("aps"): {
>       alert =     {
>           body = NEXT;
>           title = TEST;
>       };
>       sound = default; }]

Also in `setting > app` all permission accepted

Comment: Just a hint, did you [allow notification](https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201925) for your app?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot yes i did